# EndPoint: Syntax in C# - what is this?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, .net-3.5

I'm reviewing some code on the project I recently joined, and in a **C# Win Forms Application** for **.NET 3.5** I found this:

```
public void foo()
{
    //Normal code for function foo.

//This is at the end and it is left-indented just as I put it here.
EndPoint:
    {
    }
}
```

When I click "*EndPoint/Go To Definition"* it says *"Cannot Navigate to Endpoint"* but the project as a whole is pretty small and compiles/runs without error, so it's not a missing reference or anything.

**What is EndPoint and what is this syntax with the name : {}?**

Comment: kill the original developer that wrote it, it's a `goto`!

Comment: It's a label! What's that doing in your Win Forms project?

Comment: Holy crap :p I haven't seen one of those in years even in C++.  I didn't even know they kept that feature in C# :p

Comment: Kill Microsoft also for creating a feature that should be never used.

Comment: `goto` can actually be useful but there needs to be strong cause to use it. The braces are not required for a goto-statement and, I assume, were just placed there for readability.

Comment: Naming a go-to label EndPoint seems like a bad idea to me :p that was very misleading. :(

Comment: The `{}` are there to prevent a compiler error. If your remove them, the next statement is `}`, and the C# compiler doesn't like that. It spit out the following errors in my test class: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`, `Invalid expression term '}'`, and `; expected`. (Note, the code compiled fine until I removed the `{}` after the label).

Comment: Thanks for the extra research effort @ Jon Senchyna :)

Comment: never thought i seem it in C# but quite often when I was in vb6/C++ world...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its for `goto`.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2%28VS.71%29.aspx

The syntax with the colons specifies the labels where the `goto` statement will transfer control to.  You *can* use it in C#, but most developers tend to avoid it.  Sometimes it can be useful to break out of nested loops (that's the best I can come up with for a "legitimate" usage)

Here's a nice writeup on some of the more useful usages of `goto`: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/06/01/why-goto-still-exists-in-c.aspx

EDIT: Just to comment on the error you get about going to definition, that's understandable.  There is no "definition" source for the label.  Perhaps "go to definition" on the `goto Endpoint;` might jump to the label, but I'm not sure -- never tried it.  If your code that you have there only has the `Endpoint:` label but no `goto Endpoint;` anywhere, then it should be safe to delete the label because (I'm assuming) it's an unused remnant of old code.

Comment: Well it's not a "case" statement; it's not the same as switch/case if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: Touche, I meant goto label :) My heads everywhere today.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained what the `EndPoint:` is.  The extra braces are creating a new scope.  By creating an inner scope you can do something like this

```
public Foo()
{
    {
        int bar = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(bar);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(bar); //Error: "Cannot resolve symbol bar."  It does not exist in this scope.

    {
        int bar = 20;  //Declare bar again because the first bar is out of scope.
        Console.Writeline(bar);
    }
}
```